# Selectively move files & directories to new repo (preserving history)

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have a project with a structure like this:

```
src/
scripts/
db/
other_stuff/
even_more_stuff/
file1
file2
file3
```

This repository needs to be split up. db and scripts need to be split out into their own repositories, and I know that this can be easily done with `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter ...`

I also need to create a new main repository based on the current structure (including history), but *excluding* anything that is already split to its own repo *OR* any files on a specific list of files to exclude: `file1`, `file3`, `even_more_stuff`. Is there a way to use `git filter-branch` to filter out files by specific names?

The resulting main repo should simply be:

```
src/
other_stuff/
file2
```

One catch to this is I'm not supposed to make any changes to the original repository so I can't just delete `file`, `file3`, etc... and then copy the remainder to a new repository.

Comment: There's no *file history* in Git: the commits *are* the history. So it sounds like you need to construct a new set of commits. You *can* do this (rather painfully) with filter-branch, although the newfangled filter-repo is now recommended.

Comment: Note that filter-repo makes a new repository (always), while filter-branch forces you to clone first, then operate in the clone. So filter-repo is probably going to be nicer that way too.

Comment: @torek: I'm not familiar with filter-repo - is it a new feature of git, or a separate tool?

Comment: Currently still a separate tool (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) - I have not really played with it myself.

Comment: @torek Thanks :) this looks promising!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, here's how I did it using git-filter-repo:

0. Install git-filter-repo ( https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo )
1. freshly clone source repo
2. `cd my-source-repo`
3. `git filter-repo --path src --path other-stuff --path file2`
4. Check the results, remaining files and `git log` look ok.
5. clone the target repository (mine was empty)
6. `cd my-target-repo`
7. Add the source as a remote of the target: `git remote add src-repo path/to/my-source-repo`
8. pull from source repository: `git pull src-repo main --allow-unrelated-histories`
9. clean up remote: `git remote rm src-repo`
10. Push to origin: `git push --set-upstream origin main`

(change branch names where appropriate)

I've only done this once, so I don't know if there's a shorter, easier way, but this was still better than using `git filter-branch`.

Comment: Note that `filter-repo` removes the remote be default. The doc also mention that "it is definitely NOT okay to recommend `--force` on forums, Q&A sites, or in emails to other users without first carefully explaining that `--force` means putting your repositories’ data at risk." I've taken the liberty to update your answer to reflect that.